# my Messages in service broker remain in sys.transmission_queue

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I am using Service broker in two instances in two physical servers .with this instrument :

```
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Service+Broker/2797/
```

I set all certificate and all other options for both servers .I am using this code to send a message to target machine :

```
 Declare @ConversationHandle uniqueidentifier

Begin Transaction
Begin Dialog @ConversationHandle
 From Service SenderService
 To Service 'ReceiverService'
 On Contract SampleContract
 WITH Encryption=off;
SEND 
      ON CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle
      Message Type SenderMessageType
  ('<test>test</test>')
Commit
```

But when i check the target queue no messages exist.So i check the sys.transmission_queue in sender machine and i found this :

[image]

All messages are here .why ?how can i found the problem ?

I check the sys.conversation_endpoints

```
6720A2A2-C8F6-E811-80E3-40A8F038BB1F    802A7832-100B-4093-BEF3-B91ACB98EA13    1   65536   6820A2A2-C8F6-E811-80E3-40A8F038BB1F    65536   2086-12-21 10:11:09.720 CO  CONVERSING  ReceiverService NULL    1   7   A3DAEFBC-2ADA-4C46-8F44-3FC9882BADD1    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 1   0x02388E050000  -1  0   0   0   -1  0   0   0   5
```

Comment: A couple of things if look at. In sys.transmission_queue, what is in the transmission_status column? If there's nothing there, I'd look at using the ssbdiagnose utility that comes with SQL Server to look for a configuration error.

Comment: @BenThul as you can see the  transmission_status is empty

Comment: I couldn't because I'm cutting this on a phone and the picture is tiny. ssbdiagnose it is!

Comment: @BenThul what should i write in ssbdiagnose?
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn>SSBDiagnose.exe -E -d
"MYDB" FROM "senderservice" TO "ReceiverService"
An internal exception occurred: Unrecognized command line option or argument
Parameter name: -E

Comment: My suggestion would be to change your working directory to the location of the tool and run it from there.

Comment: @BenThul i found that in programfiles,but it is a commandline application ?am i right?

Comment: You're correct; it's a command line application.

Comment: @BenThul so what you mean by "change your working directory to the location of the tool and run it from there"?

Comment: `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn` and run the command from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i used this ([enter link description here](https://dbcouncil.net/2012/08/01/service-broker-concepts-and-troubleshooting/))post to find the problem .
The problem was the time different between two machines.